# Method to reverse array causes StackOverflowError

Tags: java, arrays, methods, reverse

I try to write a method to reverse an array, but I always get an StackOverFlowError. Can someone help?

Here is my code:

```
public class Exercise4_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] arr = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
        int result = reverse(arr);
        System.out.print(result);
    }

    static Integer reverse(int[] arr) {
        int n = arr.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[n-1-i];
            arr[n-1-i] = temp;
        }
        return reverse(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the recursive call for?

Comment: Well typically in recursion, you need a check to see if you should return something that isn't recursive. Otherwise - how would your recursion ever end? There is nothing to stop reverse() from calling itself over and over.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is basically like:

```
reverse() {
    ...
    reverse();
}
```

How do you think this recursion will end? A correct recursion always need a base case, a case that can terminates the recursion...

Anyway, the way you solved it doesn't need any recursion. Then remove the call to `reverse()` inside `reverse`...

Answer (score 1):

The reverse method should return a `int[]`, and this array should be your `arr` parameter. No need of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: return the int[] that you have reversed, rather than calling the same method.

The method call is causing your program to go into infinite recursion.

Here is the fixed code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] arr = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
    int result = reverse(arr);
    System.out.print(result);
}

static Integer reverse(int[] arr) {
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[n-1-i];
        arr[n-1-i] = temp;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! 
This is how i solved the problem:

```
public class Exercise4_2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] arr = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
    reverse(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(arr[i]);
      if (i < arr.length - 1) {
        System.out.print(", ");
      }
    }
}
public static void reverse(int[] arr) {
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[n-1-i];
        arr[n-1-i] = temp;
    }
}
```

}